# Algebra rules when multiplying matrices with unknown variables

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I'm about to compute the determinant of a given matrix, this matrix however contains variables instead of actual values, so I'm a bit uncertain what to do here.

I have the 3x3 matrix A:

$$A = \left(\begin{matrix} a-b-c & 2a & 2a\\ 2b & b-c-a & 2b\\ 2c & 2c &c-a-b\end{matrix}\right).$$

When computing the determinant i start off by taking the first element and multiply this with the determinant of the $2\times 2$ matrix and here I encounter the problem as I'm not sure how multiplying work out in this scenario:

$$\det(A) = (a-b-c)\left((b-c-a)(c-a-b) - (2b)(2c)\right). $$

Do I start off by multiplying $b$ with $c$, then $-a$ and then $-b$ or do I try to simply the expressions, like $b$ cancels out $-b$ etc.?

This is my attempt for the determinant of the $2\times 2$ matrix for the first part:

\begin{eqnarray*} (b-c-a)(c-a-b) &= &bc - ab -b^2 - c^2 + ac + bc - ac + a^2 + ab \\&=& a^2 - b^2 + 2ab - c^2.\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: You use the same algebra/arithmetic rules that you know. But, note that $\det(A)$ is not just what you have; you need two other cofactors... Also, there's a small error in your second calculation: the $ab$'s cancel out. And you forgot about the $-4bc$.

Comment: Yes I know it's only one cofactor, that's why i left the '...'. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Oh oops sorry I edited it out by accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the determinant of a matrix is defined in terms of sums of products, which entails the use of the standard operations of addition and multiplication, the "algebra" needed for computing the determinant is simply the standard arithmetic manipulation on variables and scalars.

First, note that you have not obtained the full expression for $\det (A)$ when expanding along the first column.

$$\begin{align} \det(A) & = (a-b-c)\Big((b-c-a)(c-a-b) - (2b)(2c)\Big) \\ 
& - \;\;2b\Big(2a(c-a-b) - (2a)(2c)\Big) \\ 
& + \;\;2c\Big((2a)(2b) - 2a(b-c-a)\Big)\end{align}$$

Also, for the product within the first term of the sum, we have (note the bold-face term, which is in contrast to your computation):

\begin{eqnarray*} (b-c-a)(c-a-b) &= &bc - ab -b^2 - c^2 + ac + bc - ac + a^2 + ab \\&=& a^2 - b^2 + {\bf 2bc} - c^2.\end{eqnarray*}

Then for the complete first term of the sum, we need to compute:

$$(a - b - c)\Big((a^2 - b^2 + 2bc - c^2)- 4bc\Big) = (a - b - c)(a^2 - b^2 -c^2 - 2bc)$$

The second and third term in $\det(A)$ should be a bit less tedious to compute.

Comment: Oh i see, actually meant 2bc, just mistyped it. Thanks for the answer. The second cofactor should also have a '-' in front it I'm not mistaken for the full expression of the determinant.

Comment: You're welcome, John. I thought perhaps the $2ab$ might have been a typo!.

Comment: I edited my previous comment a few seconds before you replied, so you probably didn't see it, so I will ask again in this comment. The second cofactor should also have a '-' in front it if I'm not mistaken for the full expression of the determinant?

Comment: Yes, @John. You're correct. You've got this down-pat pretty well!

Comment: @amWhy: Nice write-up +1